# How to implement this in Android? 

Tags: java, android, puzzle, touch-event

I want to add the value of tile positioning 1,0 with tile 1,1 when on touching the tile at 1,0 and display the result at tile 1,1. After the addition operation the tile 1,0 should display nothing and the focus should disappear. The focus should reappear again when I touch the value containing tiles. Also I want the tiles to be sliding.what will be the best approach to do this in android. Here is a link for better understand my question [the game link](http://mypuzzle.org/sliding/)

[image]

Comment: This problem has a number of subparts (data structure, logic, UI, user interaction, etc.). Break your problem down into these parts, and tackle them separately. Then come back here when you get stuck on specific aspects of the problem.

Comment: Check this: http://goo.gl/ZBcKh

Comment: @PM-PareshMayani:thanks bhai........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete example for what you are looking for. Just download the source and try this it might help you out further. [Move & Drag Images](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=explorer&chrome=true&srcid=0B0wYSnCBkoR6ZTBiMGNiNmYtZWQ4Mi00ZTIxLWFlMWItMjE3OGVlMDdkMjRj&hl=en_US)

Answer (score 2):

use `GridView` for this. Here is [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html).

Comment: :thank u bro ..could u give me some site address,which i can refer.........for developing this...

Comment: try this: http://www.firstdroid.com/2011/02/06/android-tutorial-gridview-with-icon-and-text/, http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/09/extending-and-customizing-gridview-with.html